# Custom css and JS on some admin pages in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I created a plugin to export some specific content in Wordpress ( called **cav** and located in **/wp-content/plugins/cav** ) and I added its admin menu link in the Tools main menu as follows:

```
define( 'CAV_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'CAV_URL', plugins_url()."/cav" );

function cavlfo_admin_enqueue($hook) {
global $post;
if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook=='tools.php?page=CAV' ) {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'cavlfo_style', CAV_URL. '/css/cav.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style(  'cavlfo_targetted', CAV_URL.'/css/targettedcss.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script(  'cavlfo_targetted', CAV_URL.'/js/targetted.js', array("jquery") );
}
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cavlfo_admin_enqueue' );
```

All this  works  fine when I used

`if( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook=='tools.php' ){ . . .}`

but I want it to work ONLY when it's actually

`if( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook=='tools.php?page=CAV' ){ . . .}` (Only on the  page is CAV )

Any suggestion?

Comment: After some digging, I found this and it did the trick http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41207/how-do-i-enqueue-styles-scripts-on-certain-wp-admin-pages

Comment: suggestion...  You can also asnwer your own question, it will help future people to find the answer right away, instead of navigating through links.

Comment: I just  did. Thank @andrepaulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I got this:

```
function CAV_options_page()
{
  $submenu= add_submenu_page(
        'tools.php',
        'Cav Options',
        'Cav Options',
        'manage_options',
        'CAV',
        'CAV_options_page_html'
    );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $submenu, 'CAV_custom_enqueue' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' . $submenu, 'CAV_custom_enqueue' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'CAV_options_page');
```

Then I put the styles and scripts that need to be enqueued in a function

```
function CAV_custom_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style(  'cav_targetted', CAV_URL.'/css/targettedcss.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script(  'cav_targetted', CAV_URL.'/js/targetted.js', array("jquery") );
}
```

I hope it helps someone.